# vb.net data not saved sql compact database when after closing the application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I did small application, to save insert data to table....

The application is not saving the data after the application close..

Can any one tell me what is the wrong in the code.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe


Public Class Form1

Public connstring As New String("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\test_db.sdf")
Public sqlconn As New SqlCeConnection(connstring)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim name As New String("jaifar")
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCeCommand("Insert Into table1 (id) Values('" + name + "')", sqlconn)
    If sqlconn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlconn.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Test_dbDataSet1.table1)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    sqlconn.Close()
    sqlconn = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Test_dbDataSet1.table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Test_dbDataSet1.table1)

 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Look in the bin/debug folder, there you will probably find a database with data - fix is to use a full path in your connection string - data source=C:\projects\proj\test.sdf

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to work around this:

1. If you select local database file in the Solution Explorer window, you will see a property called ‘Copy to Output’ in the Properties window. By default it is set to ‘Copy Always’ which means that on each build, the data files in the project folder will be copied to the output folder overwriting the existing data files if any. You can set this property to Copy Never and then manually put a copy of the data file in the output folder. This way, on subsequent builds, the project system will leave the datafile in the output folder and not try to overwrite it with the one from the project. The downside is that you still have two copies so after you modify the database file using the app, if you want to work on those changes in the project, you need to copy it to the project manually and vise-versa.
2. You can leave the data file outside the project and create a connection to it in Database Explorer. When the IDE asks you to bring the file into the project, just say no. This way, both the design-time and the run-time will be using the same data file but the downside is that the path in the connection string will be hard coded and therefore it’ll be harder to share the project and deploy the app. Before deploying the app, just make sure to replace the full path in the settings with a relative path.

Source: https://arnulfo.wordpress.com/2007/07/21/visual-studio-and-local-databases/

Answer (score -1):

after

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

then write

```
sqlconn.Close()
```

Cause, when you have write execute, better close it.
You must know that saving to dataset with database is not same.. Dataset is temporaly in your program, mean still not get change in database.

and, where is our + name + value??
Like,
mycommand.addwithvalue("name", the value place)